# Sorting object property by key array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

If I have a JavaScript object such as:

```
const group = {
    Gp1: 1, 
    Gp12:1, 
    Gp11:2, 
    Gp10: 0,
    Gp2: 1, 
    Gp5: 4,
    Gp3: 4,
    Gp4: 4,
    Gp6: 4,
};
```

I want to make sortable ascending by key of the array
with this code

```
const sortable = Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(group).sort(([,a],[,b]) => a-b)
);
console.log(sortable);
```

I end up with

```
{
  Gp1: 1,
  Gp10: 0,
  Gp11: 2,
  Gp12: 1,
  Gp2: 1,
  Gp3: 4,
  Gp4: 4,
  Gp5: 4,
  Gp6: 4
}
```

Is there a way to sort the properties based on key array? So that I end up with

```
{
  Gp1: 1,
  Gp2: 1,
  Gp3: 4,
  Gp4: 4,
  Gp5: 4,
  Gp6: 4,
  Gp10: 0,
  Gp11: 2,
  Gp12: 1,
}
```

Comment: Doesn't make sense to sort object properties in order? Because you eventually going to take `key` and fetch the value from `object`.

Comment: `Object.entries()` returns an array of arrays. In the "inner" arrays the first element is the property, the second element the value. You skip the first element and use the second. Just adapt it...

Comment: @HR01M8055 I do this because I want to avoid looping more..in my code

Comment: You should use sort for sorting like this: https://www.javascripttutorial.net/array/javascript-sort-an-array-of-objects/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `string#localeCompare` to sort based on numeric value by passing `{numeric: true}`.

```js
const o = { Gp1: 1, Gp10: 0, Gp11: 2, Gp12: 1, Gp2: 1, Gp3: 4, Gp4: 4, Gp5: 4, Gp6: 4 },
      result = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(o).sort((a,b) => a[0].localeCompare(b[0], undefined, {numeric: true})));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer..but this doesn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

Are you finding something like this?

```
const sortable = Object.fromEntries(
Object.entries(group).sort(([a,],[b,]) => parseInt(a.replace('Gp', '')) - parseInt(b.replace('Gp', '')))
);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer..but this doesn't work for me..the result is the same as my code